# Trouble with window.print after having altered page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I am in trouble with the print function offered by javascript: It doesn't print the current page.

From the beginning: The purpose of the page is to take input from the user, process it and display a result. In fact, it is a simple form with a couple of input fields. With the help of jquery the input given by the user is interpreted and a result is displayed. If the input is satisfactory, a plus sign on a green background in a div-container is displayed. If not, a minus sign on a red background is displayed.

Now, the problem: The user is offered a print-button. That is not 21st century, but a requirement. The printout looks pretty fine thanks to the print.css. But there is one problem: The div-containers only appear in their unprocessed shape. **No matter what the input of the user was, the div-containers are printed in their initial state** (meaning: gray background).

The div-containers are changed by using the jquery-function addclass() or removeclass(). On the screen, everything works fine. But a look at the source code after having processed the input of the user still reveals an unchanged div-container. Therefore the print result is short of its purpose.

How do I convince the browser to print the altered div container instead of the initial one (as it was at the time of loading the page)? What am I missing here?

For your help, lets have a look at the crucial parts of the source code:

a) how the css files are linked in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/standard.css">     
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="styles/print.css" />
```

b) how the print button is handled:

```
$('a#print').click(function(e){        
    e.preventDefault();        
    window.print(); 
});
```

c) how the div containers are altered:

```
$('div#result').addClass('res_red'); 
$('div#result').removeClass('res_green'); 
$('div#result').removeClass('res_zero');
```

Again: On the screen everything works fine. Just the print-out is in a mess...

Answer (score 0):

i do not get that.
do you load print.css to all users? or just who clicks the "Print" button?

nothing is wrong in your code. im afraid its just css rules not applying right.
(maybe some `!important` or just override not strong enough*)

***override not strong enough example:**

css:

```
div.container div.class-a:hover {
color: grey;
}
.container div:hover {
color: red;
}
```

the last class will **not** override the first one due to not strong enough selector.
so color remain grey on hover, although the last class written below.